Not able to move file
I am trying to execute below command but,getting error like "cannot overwrite non- directory with directory.
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec mv bkp {} \;

Bkp folder is in current path.
Please assist

The standard usage of the mv command is
mv [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST

i.e. the first non-option argument is taken as the source and the second as the destination. So
mv bkp {} \; attempts to move the directory bkp to {} (the latest matching file found by find).
You need either mv {} bkp \; or (safer IMHO) mv -t bkp {} \; which uses the GNU -t target directory extension.
You could also consider move multiple files at once this way:
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec mv -t bkp {} +

Note however that if bkp is in the current directory, find will descend into it and attempt to move its matching files back into it - so best to either move it outside of . or else use a -prune or ! -path test to skip it.
